Deconvolution, NN-resize convolution
I was reading following paper: Deconvolution and Checkerboard Artifacts.
The text says that

Both deconvolution and the different resize-convolution approaches are linear operations, and can be interpreted as matrices.

To this explanation they add following image:



How are the matrices computed? I think they should represent how input features influence the output of the deconvolution. But I really don't know how they are actually computed.
